# How to prevent (or limit) Oracle Reports Builder 10g crashing

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, report, reportbuilder, oraclereports

Reports Builder version 10.1.2.0.2

DB version: 10.2.0.4.0 (64 Bit)

Oracle Reports Builder is crashing so regularly now that it is almost unuseable, we have to backup and save after every minor change "just in case" and inevitably, when anyone forgets to save it crashes immediately :-)

In light of this, we are having Reports installed on a vanilla PC with only what is needed for Reports Builder to run in the hope that the lack of other general business PC software might prevent the crashing/restarting that we have been experiencing with Reports Builder.

I realise the Reports Builder has never been a hugely stable development tool (even my Oracle Corp. course tutor admitted as much) but I've not seen it this bad before.

Has anyone out there managed to get Reports Builder 10g installed with good stability? If so, do you have any tips or information as to how you got it this way? What version of Reports Builder are you using?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We encountered this instability as well. I think Oracle Reports Builder is famous for this. What we did to minimize the crashes was to use it inside a VM(running in VMWare ESX) and just Remote Desktop into it. We created multiple XP accounts so multiple developers can share the same VM.

I know this sounds **downright crazy** and **does not make any sense** but it did noticeably reduce the frequency of crashes. I think the best solution is just to drink a pitcher of patience, save often and try to hold on to your sanity.

Comment: I think the organisation i'm working for has drunk more than a pitcher of patience on this issue. I'll see if we can run Reports inside a VM and see if that helps. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Not entirely. It was a good suggestion though and as the only answer I have accepted it as the best. Oracle reports are flaky to say the least but anything that can improve its uptime is a bonus :-)

Comment: Haha so you tried it? Did it at least reduce(based on your perception at least) the crashes? And yep, Oracle's position on this is to just deny it and send useless patches that don't really do anything. A good lot they are.